# How can I send inputstream arraylist to REST service

Tags: java, json, jersey, inputstream

My requirement is to send a value object which contains a list of inputstreams, tried different media types but none is helping me. How can we send json string, inputstream together. Could you please help me with my problem.

```
@POST
@Path("/upload_stream_vo")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response uploadDoc(final List<InputStream> streamList) 
throws RestException
```

Comment: Would not you be using  @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> uploadfiles ?

Comment: Check out the Jersey docs [chapter on Multipart](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart). That's what you need to use if you want to have multiple "parts"

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately we are not using spring, jersey implementation. Your solution is very much suitable for my problem, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your reply. combination of "Multipart and StreamDataBodyPart" did the work for me. The link you provided is really helpful.

Comment: MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).bodyPart(bodyPart1).bodyPart(bodyPart2)
                    .bodyPart(streamPart1).bodyPart(streamPart2).bodyPart(streamPart3);